# I want to make a python number table

Tags: python-3.x

I don;t know how to make 4 by 3 chart. It's only printing one line chart. please help me!

```
for x in range(1, 64, 2):
    print(x, end='')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOWUr.png)

Comment: When do you expect to move to a new line? Construct an `if` condition to check that (e.g. check if `x+1` divisible by `8`) and then print a newline. BTW it is recommended that you put your expected output directly here rather than link to an external image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works and the width of the table can also be changed:

```
nums = range(1, 64, 2)
width = 4

for i in range(len(nums)):

    if (i + 1) % width == 0 and i != 0:
        print(str(nums[i]).rjust(2))
    else:
        print(str(nums[i]).rjust(2), end = " ")
```

Output:

```
 1  3  5  7
 9 11 13 15
17 19 21 23
25 27 29 31
33 35 37 39
41 43 45 47
49 51 53 55
57 59 61 63
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't have known %,rjust.